# Send and Receive request Code Android Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Good day.I want to send and receive an request code through my own activities without using intents as it will normally be done for example contacts activity or any other external ones.Lets say i got some BuyCoins activity and i start it like this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BuyCoins.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, BUY_COINS_REQUEST_CODE);
```

So by googling everyone was using intents not this way,but i do not want to use intents for such scenario,i want to do it default.
In buy coins class everyone said i should do something like

```
 setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

But where i get the `BUY_COINS_REQUEST_CODE`?how do i give back the request code from BuyCoins class?Someone can tell me please?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to my own answer though.Keep an class of constants or however you want.Make an final static public variable for your request code,pass it to `startActivityForResult()` as usually you would do and start your desired activity.The trick is here now.Whenever you want to finish your started desired activity to give result back to the starter of that activity just before `finish()` call this method

```
setResult(Constants.MY_OWN_REQUEST_CODE, myOwnCreatedIntentData);
```

and you are good to go,meaning now you can in your caller activity do the next

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Constants.MY_OWN_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (data != null) {
                boolean someData= data.getExtras().getBoolean(Constants.SOME_DATA_KEY);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

and thats it your done

Comment: You don't need to do that explicitly, its handled automatically. In your `setResult()` you are not setting `requestCode` but, `resultCode`

Answer (score 0):

BUY_COINS_REQUEST_CODE is a constant integer Value 
declare as **Instance variables** 
`final int BUY_COINS_REQUEST_CODE =101;//or any`

**SecondActivity**

```
Intent intent=new Intent();  
setResult(FirstActivity.BUY_COINS_REQUEST_CODE ,intent);  
 finish();//finishing activity
```

now in **FirstActivity**

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case :BUY_COINS_REQUEST_CODE 
            if (resultCode == BUY_COINS_REQUEST_CODE  && null != data) {

                //do something
            }
            break;
   }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: AFAIK, the code won't run because in your `setResult()` above you just set the result code as `FirstActivity.BUY_COINS_REQUEST_CODE` but, in your `onActivityResult()` you are checking for `RESULT_OK`.

Comment: @Shaishav now am i ok?

Comment: Yeah, it would run but, this doesn't change anything. I fail to understand why this is needed at all. Why not show success with the recommended `RESULT_OK`?

Answer (score 0):

Your SecondActivity should set data as follows:

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
Intent.putExtra("coins","coins value");
 setResult(RESULT_OK,intent); finish();
```

//finishing activity

And in FirstActivity Override onActvityResult method as follows:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); switch (requestCode) { case BUY_COINS_REQUEST_CODE : if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) { 
String coins= data.getStringExtra("coins"); 
} 
break; } }
```

Hope it help to solve your problem.